# how to use data list in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

**how to use data list in visual studio?**

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this tutorial:

[**Displaying Data with the DataList and Repeater Controls**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498210.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Another couple of good resources are...

http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/aspnet_datalist.asp

http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Using-the-DataList-control/5747